# Is convergence of of vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$ equivalent to the elementwise convergence even in nonstandard distance?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm wondering, for $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^k$, whether $x_n \to x$ iff $x_n^p \to x^p$, for $p=1,\cdots,k$.

The equivalence is direct for the standard Euclidean norm, norm defined by maximum of it component, and $L2$ norm.

If a distance satisfies the symmetry and triangle inequality, does this distance also means the two conditions are equivalent?

Comment: (You are using superscripts for indexing the vector.) I think the question isn't precise enough. You want $$d_k(x_n,x)\to 0 \iff d_{1,p}(x_n^p , x^p) \to 0$$what is the relationship of the (potentially different for each $p$) metric $d_{1,p}$ on $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d_k$?

Comment: If you're using distance functions induced by a norm, it doesn't matter. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite dimensional and on a finite dimensional space every norm is equivalent (if a sequence converges in one norm, it converges in all the others too).

Comment: If you are considering any metric, then the answer is 'no'. Just take the discrete metric ($d(a,b) = 0$, iff $a=b, d(a,b) = 1$ otherwise). Then you can have the sequence $x_n= (\frac1n, \frac1n,\ldots)$ whose coordinates each converge to $0$, but the sequence does not converge to $(0,0,\ldots)$ in that distance.